# SIMPLE Delete line from cell?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007, vba

Hello I'm trying to delete all the rows where in column B the members value is over 1000.
I tried this step by step and tried first getting rid of all the unecessary data from B cells and leave just the line with the members. 
I noticed there are 5 lines and the members line is the 6'th one. I searched for hours and I still don't get it HOW TO DELETE THE FIRST 5 LINES. Could you please offer me a hand of help? Im sure its soo easy but I cant find it.

I have this:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Delete5TextLines()
Dim c As Range, s
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each c In Range("B1", Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

**********

Next c
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

this is the .csv file:
http://we.tl/vNcyfg9Wus

[image]

Comment: Nothing happens when I download your example.

Comment: @Davesexcel hello. I know its not working. The file that you downloaded contains only the raw data that need to be processed.

Comment: I'm telling you I can't download your file,nothing happens when I click download.

Comment: @Davesexcel I'm sorry. I reuploaded it!

Comment: @pnuts hy there. I sorry I'm really new to this. May you show me an example?

Comment: Pic added for better explaination

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, this is not very elegant, but the first thing that I came up with, that kinda works.

use this formula to delete the last word in your bulk of text ("members")

Assuming your text is in A1:

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","|",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))))-1)
```

This formula gets you the last word of a text, in this case the number of members (because we deleted the word "members)

Assuming you put the formula above in A2

```
=IF(ISERR(FIND(" ",A2)),"",RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-FIND("*",SUBSTITUTE(A2," ","*",LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2," ",""))))))
```

Now you should have extracted the number of members. If this value is <5000 you can delete the row with a vba loop that should look like this:

```
Sub deleteRowsAfterMembers

Dim i as Integer

i = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Rows.Count

While i > 0 Do

If (CellWithMemberCount).Value < 5000 Then 

ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Rows(i).Delete

End If

i = i-1

Loop

End Sub
```

That'll (hopefully) do it.

Comment: I found this: http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=171305 it deletes the second line of a column. I just dont know how to adapt it to delethe the first one and run it 5 times

Comment: this is supposed to delete the first line http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/565574-remove-first-line-inside-cell.html   but it's not working for me -_-

Comment: What exactly are you trying to delete? A row? As in Row 25 or do you want to delete lines of text within a cell?
If you want to delete the first 5 rows(!) you can just write (not so elegantly) Sheets(1).Rows(1).delete 5 times.

Comment: sorry for the missunderstanding. As in the above posted pic I want to delete the first 5 lines from the cell B so that cell B should contain only "9,877 members" There are 5 lines before "9,877 members" but they are long ones. If you open the .csv in notepad or sublime you will see the first 5 lines. I just want to get rid of them :)

Comment: And one last question: is "XXX members" always at the very end of the text in cell BY?

Comment: Yes, it's always the last line from each cell. I could also delete all the lines from each cell except the last one.

Comment: edited the wohle thing. this should fix your entire problem, not just delete 5 rows per cell. (;

Comment: You are welcome. Now you can mark the answer as most useful. (;

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you delete entire rows using a **loop**, you should start at the bottom of the range and work the loop upwards.

**EDIT#1:**

Assuming that there are at least five lines within a cell and the lines are separated by *Chr(10)* then this will remove the first 5 lines:

```
Sub marine()
    ary = Split(ActiveCell.Value, Chr(10))
    t = ""
    For i = 5 To UBound(ary)
        t = t & Chr(10) & ary(i)
    Next i

    If Len(t) > 1 Then
        t = Mid(t, 2)
    Else
        t = ""
    End If
    ActiveCell.Value = t
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for that but I need to delete the first 5 lines inside a cell :)

Comment: Thank you soooo much!!! Its working perfectly. Could you also show me how to implement this in a loop for all B cells? I tried like this: http://pastie.org/9996015    but it seems it goes into a infineite loop becausr excel is crusing.

Comment: @AlexStanese  I will get back to you in a couple of hours.

Comment: @Tom hey I made it!! I made a while cell is not empty and inserted your code. Now its working perfectly. Thank you very much! Yout saved my day!!